# Trying to make sense of Android Studio gradle build tasks between release and debug build variants

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Using Android Studio 2.1.2, Gradle 2.10 and Android Gradle plugin 2.1.0, in a project and modules to build a library AAR.

I'm looking to insert my own behaviors by way of Android Studio module custom tasks. I'm in the IDE, flipping between debug and release variants and executing Build/Rebuild Project watching the Gradle console.

My questions:
I understand why "configure by convention" tasks flip between running canned "debug" versus "release" tasks, but I don't understand why the canned sequences of tasks are functionally different between the two variants. For example, when rebuilding debug, I see these core tasks executed:
...
:LibraryModule:bundleDebug
:LibraryModule:compileDebugSources
:LibraryModule:assembleDebug
...

When rebuilding release, I see these core tasks executed:
...
:LibraryModule:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:LibraryModule:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:LibraryModule:compileReleaseSources
...

What? Where are the bundleRelease and assembleRelease tasks? Where in the release build do I hook in my custom task (since assembleRelease or bundleRelease aren't called)?

Can I use the Android Studio "Edit Configurations..." IDE feature to setup custom build configurations to execute "Make Project (F7)" for AAR targets. And if yes, how? Specifically, what do I put in a "Gradle project:" field to target a specific module's build and what exactly, semantic and syntax wise, do I put in the "Tasks:" field?

Last question. After doing a full rebuild of a library module (to produce a .AAR file) with the build variant set to debug, I see the following task executions:
...
:LibraryModule:bundleDebug
:LibraryModule:compileDebugSources
:LibraryModule:assembleDebug
...

The order of execution doesn't seem right. I would think the order would be:
...
:LibraryModule:assembleDebug
:LibraryModule:compileDebugSources
:LibraryModule:bundleDebug
...

Am I being faked out by dependency chain output or what?

Comment: I think I can answer my "Last question" here. Gradle is all about being dependency chain driven. Therefore, bundleDebug, is called first, which probably zips up an AAR target for deployment, probably figures out, hey, can't do that yet because there is no binary assemblies, i.e. shared libraries, so compileDebugSources is called to product binary object files, and then assemblyDebug is called to link the binary object files into a shared library.

Comment: But really, if gradle were purely dependency chain driven, you see bundleDebug first, assembleDebug next and then finally compileDebugSources last. The gradle build logic seems inconsistent, if not outright confusing. I miss make.